# XPATH - locating specific children element

Tags: xpath, robotframework

in my DOM I have like 3 tables and each table has several input fields, is it possible to write xpath let say for 3rd input of 2nd table
I can locate only first input of each table, so I assume that its bracket thing

i did try
(//table[@class='table-name'])[2](//input)[3] 
also
((//table[@class=‘table-name’])[2])(//input)[3]

Comment: correction
(//table[@class=‘table-name’]) [2] (//input) [3]

Comment: This is not valid XPath though. You can't have a `(` after a `]`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"the third input out of the second table":

```
((//table)[2]//input)[3]
```

- first, this selects all tables from the document, regardless of their position `//table`.
- then it picks the second one from that set `(//table)[2]`
- going from this one, it selects all nested inputs `(//table)[2]//input`
- and from this set, it picks the third one

---

Note that `(//table)[2]` is *"from all tables anywhere, take the second one"* whereas `//table[2]` is *"take all tables who are the second child of their respective parents"*. The the former expression can only ever select a single table, while the latter can select more than one.